# How to set opacity of svg from 0 - 1 when hovering a parent element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'd like to create a hover statement on a container, where when i hover over the Parent, it moves 40px to the right, and a yellow box sets its opacity from 0 to 1. The 40px to the right works just fine. But the box problem is killing me.

```css
.Parent:hover {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(40px, 0);
  width: 1180px;
  height: 199px;
  left: 46px;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <svg class="YELLOW_BOX" viewBox="0 0 1180 140">
<rect class="Yellow_box_class" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="1180" height="140"></rect></svg>
  <div class="TEXT_Class">
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i set the opacity of "YELLOW_BOX" to 1, when hovering the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. This seemed to solve my issue

```
.Parent:hover .Yellow_box_class { 
  opacity: 1; 
  fill: rgba(255,237,89,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
.parent:hover .yellow_box {
     opacity: 0 !important;
}
```